# How do I fix the linker error when building GCC on Mac M1?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a GCC cross-compiler for `x86` on M1, but it failed during linking.

This is the error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___aarch64_cas8_acq_rel", referenced from:
      _macho_add in libbacktrace.a(macho.o)
      _backtrace_initialize in libbacktrace.a(macho.o)
      _backtrace_dwarf_add in libbacktrace.a(dwarf.o)
  "___aarch64_swp4_acq", referenced from:
      _backtrace_free in libbacktrace.a(mmap.o)
      _backtrace_alloc in libbacktrace.a(mmap.o)
  "_host_hooks", referenced from:
      c_common_no_more_pch() in c-pch.o
      toplev::main(int, char**) in libbackend.a(toplev.o)
      gt_pch_save(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o)
      gt_pch_restore(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

For context, I'm using `gcc-11.3.0` installed via `brew`. Additionally, `gmp`, `mpfr`, and `libmpc` are also installed via `brew`.

Below are the steps I used:

```
cd /tmp/src
curl -O https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-11.3.0/gcc-11.3.0.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-11.3.0.tar.xz
mkdir gcc-build
cd gcc-build
../gcc-11.3.0/configure --target=$TARGET --prefix="$PREFIX" --disable-nls --disable-libssp --enable-language=c --without-headers --with-gmp="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gmp/6.2.1_1" --with-mpfr="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpfr/4.1.0" --with-mpc="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libmpc/1.2.1"
make all-gcc all-target-libgcc
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue myself. My builtin Apple `clang` is able to build `binutils`, `gcc`, and `gdb` as well.